# JS RegEx: simple match with optional parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I think I don't really get RegEx stuff, so I need help matching the following simple pattern:

```
SOME_TEXT _Syn: SYN_TEXT _Ant: ANT_TEXT
```

quotes are decorative, `X_TEXT` is any text (that does not contain `_Syn`: or `_Ant`: that are special abbreviation), _Syn or _Ant parts are optional

I need to get `SOME_TEXT`, `SYN_TEXT` and `ANT_TEXT` in array

So for example if _Syn part not present (input is `SOME_TEXT _Ant: ANT_TEXT`) result should be `[SOME_TEXT, '', ANT_TEXT]`

Tried different approaches with lazy modifiers but fails to implement it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your possible input can look like. Can you give a few explicit examples? And maybe show the regex code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(.*?)(?:_Syn:(.*?))?(?:_Ant:(.*?))?$/
```

The important parts are the `?` after the `.*` which make them reluctant (not greedy) and the `$` at the end that forces the match in spite of all of the optional matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
var n=str.match(/(SOME|SYN|ANT)_TEXT/g);
```

`n` would contain an array of matched strings